# In readRDS(nsInfoFilePath) : error reading the file

Tags: r, rvest

***an error*** has occurred when I was trying to deal with html files in r using the *rvest* package.
the code is as following:

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_in_the_United_States_by_state"
h <- read_html(url)
class(h)
tab <- h %>% html_nodes("table")
```

then, the error message is:
***Error in readRDS(nsInfoFilePath) : error reading from connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readRDS(nsInfoFilePath) : error reading the file***
could you help me please solve this error?

Comment: The error would come from somewhere else than the code you provided.

Comment: @Phil is it solvable, i tried to remove packages and to upload them again, but in vain.

Comment: Presumably, but without knowing more about what rds file you're trying to read, it's not possible to help.